# Move-Item, mv and Get-Command not recognized as internal or external command in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-11, neovim

Why are this essential commands just not recognized? I am on Windows 11, using the new Terminal app with Powershell. I can't even run Get-Host to get the Powershell version. I am using a terminal buffer form NeoVim, maybe that can cause the issue? If so how can I fix it?

Comment: Please have a look at [how to write a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). *"Why doesn't this work"* is practically impossible to troubleshoot. It gets a lot easier if you formulate the question as "I'm using *<application version>* on *<Operating Sytem version>*. When I do *<action>*, I should see *<expected result>*. However I see *<actual result>*, and these *<exact error messages enclosed in code brackets `{ }`>*."

Comment: You may have Terminal open, but do you have PowerShell open in that terminal? I'm guessing that you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah in fact the terminal buffer from neovim runs cmd.exe ;)